# SQL: Same no ranking

Tags: sql

my table include only two columns, My purpose ranking no columns and add to new column

```
 no foto
 1  foto1
 1  foto2
 2  foto3
 2  foto4
 2  foto5
 3  foto6
 3  foto7
```

I want to do like below table

```
 no foto   newcolomn
 1  foto1   1
 1  foto2   2
 2  foto3   1
 2  foto4   2
 2  foto5   3
 3  foto6   1
 3  foto7   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select no, foto, row_number() over(partition by no order by foto) newcolumn
from mytable
```